# Getting excerpt in loop within loop – Twenty sixteen theme Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

Hello fellow wordpress expirienced users.
I’m having a struggle while doing a latest 3 posts excerpt with thumbnail in my homepage in Wordpress TwentySixteen Theme.
I tried various possibilities but i cant get it running.

The goal is to look the posts like this:
http://caenthemes.cekuj.net/?s=p%C5%99%C3%ADsp%C4%9Bvek

My thought is to use an already made template for the seach page.
But than it the text of the excerpt is nowhere:
http://caenthemes.cekuj.net/
The fact that its not styled leave aside please.

The code of the main page:

```
 <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying main-page without title.
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
?>

<section id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <!--<header class="entry-header">
    <?php the_title('<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>'); ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <div class="wp-page-content">
        <?php
        the_content();
        wp_link_pages(array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __('Pages:', 'twentysixteen') . '</span>',
            'after' => '</div>',
            'link_before' => '<span>',
            'link_after' => '</span>',
            'pagelink' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __('Page', 'twentysixteen') . ' </span>%',
            'separator' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">, </span>',
        ));
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</section>   
<section>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2>
            <?php
            if (get_locale() == 'cs_CZ') {
                echo "Nejnovější příspěvky";
            } else {
                echo "Latest posts";
            }
            ?>
        </h2>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'offset' => 0,
        'category' => '',
        'category_name' => '',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'include' => '',
        'exclude' => '',
        'meta_key' => '',
        'meta_value' => '',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_mime_type' => '',
        'post_parent' => '',
        'author' => '',
        'author_name' => '',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true
    );
    $myposts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
        get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'search');
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</section><!-- #wp-page-content-## -->
```

I’m 80% sure that i’m not handling right the inner loop within the main loop of twenty sixteen. Just to cover all posibilities i was also trying to do it not via get template but still i only get the posts categories titles and thumbnails but not the excerpt.
Can you help me with this ?
The whole page is based on twenty sixteen theme with my modifications.
Thank you very much,
Caen Ragestorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to SJP i made it work. So the full code working for me is here, hope anyone else will find it usefull:

```
    <section id="latest-posts">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2>
            <?php
            if (get_locale() == 'cs_CZ') {
                echo "Nejnovější příspěvky";
            } else {
                echo "Latest posts";
            }
            ?>
        </h2>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'suppress_filters' => true
        );
        $latestPost = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($latestPost->have_posts()) : $latestPost->the_post();
            ?>
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <?php the_title(sprintf('<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url(get_permalink())), '</a></h2>'); ?>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->
                <div class="post-summary">
                    <a class="post-thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" aria-hidden="true">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', array('alt' => the_title_attribute('echo=0'))); ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="entry-summary">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php if ('post' === get_post_type()) : ?>

                    <footer class="entry-footer">
                        <?php twentysixteen_entry_meta(); ?>
                        <?php
                        edit_post_link(
                                sprintf(
                                        /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
                                        __('Edit<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'twentysixteen'), get_the_title()
                                ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>'
                        );
                        ?>
                    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->

                    <?php else : ?>

                    <?php
                    edit_post_link(
                            sprintf(
                                    /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
                                    __('Edit<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'twentysixteen'), get_the_title()
                            ), '<footer class="entry-footer"><span class="edit-link">', '</span></footer><!-- .entry-footer -->'
                    );
                    ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </article>
                <?php
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Nice day to you all.
Caen Ragestorm

www.CaenRagestorm.cz

Answer (score 0):

For getting post details such as title,content and featured image you can use this code :

```
$latestPost = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'posts', 'posts_per_page' =>-1,'order' => 'ASC') );
while ( $latestPost->have_posts() ) : $latestPost->the_post();
       $sTitle                = the_title();
       $sContent              = the_content();
       $feat_image_latestPost = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
endwhile;
```

Re write CSS according to your requirement.

Comment: thanks for the code, but i'm not sure that it will work with the excerpt ? because thats what's not working properly. Probably might work getting the_excerpt() instead of content?